# Finishing old pine floors in a bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, pine

So my dad and I have this house built in 1880. Floors are 1" pine tongue and groove with no subfloor. My dad really wants to finish the pine floor in the bathroom, and while I'm not convinced this is the best idea I think it will be hard to talk him out of it.

So I'm wondering, what will give the hardest and most waterproof finish for pine floors in a bathroom? Of course we'll need to sand the floors which is going to be its own battle, along with sealing them. After some research it seems like the options are:

- wax/oil
- lacquer
- catalyzed finish

It seems like the catalyzed option will be the hardest/most waterproof, but I am honestly a bit out of my expertise here.

As a bonus, the floors are original so they should be pretty high quality cuts of pine from old growth forest rather than new, softer growth.

Comment: Are you in the UK?  You don't mention polyurethane, which would be the usual choice in the US.

Comment: @batsplatsterson why is polyurethane the usual choice? I am in California by the coast

Comment: polyurethane is very practical - durable, waterproof, easy to apply, and low maintenance.